# XML DTD Entities - в чем разница при включении?

Tags: xml

Во всех примерах реализуется вот так:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>

<!DOCTYPE address [
   <!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
   <!ENTITY name "Tanmay patil">
   <!ENTITY company "TutorialsPoint">
   <!ENTITY phone_no "(011) 123-4567">
]>

<address>
   &name;
   &company;
   &phone_no;
</address>
```

Но и так работает:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>

<!DOCTYPE address [
   <!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
   <!ENTITY name "Tanmay patil">
   <!ENTITY company "TutorialsPoint">
   <!ENTITY phone_no "(011) 123-4567">
]>


   &name;
   &company;
   &phone_no;
```

Насколько правильно и есть ли разница при включении без тега **address** в втором варианте?

Comment: Без корневого элемента это работать не может. Проверил в Visual Studio - ошибка. Проверил в первом попавшемся валидаторе xml онлайн - ошибка. / Чем проверяете?

Comment: Я запускаю всю эту конструкцию в приложении написанном на Java. Возможно у него своя валидация и он игнорирует. Но, по спецификации вроде как тег нужен и видимо работа без него это больше исключение.

Comment: Лучше использовать валидации по XML-схеме (XSD) вместо DTD. XSD доступны с 2001 года.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, пригодиться. Но в данном случае не получится по XSD, там идет включение внешнего файла через entities, а XSD это не разрешает делать.